# Symfony 4 How to change language Step by Step

Tags: symfony, multilingual

I can not understand the page translation mechanism. Translations for a specific language I keep in the yml file Translation can be obtained in two ways:

1. Holding the currently selected translation in the session

How can I change my language? The documentation even gives you a ready code https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html

Only at what point does the language change? I create a separate controller to which I pass a parameter using GET and execute the code in the controller?

```
$lang = $request->query->get('lang', null);
if(!is_null($lang)) { 
    request->setLocale($lang);
}
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index.index'));
```

In order to not write the same code in any controller, I should have one controller that only changes the language and returns the page to the previous one. Only returning to the previous page via redirect does not pass the Request with a new language only the class given in the documentation uses the default language.

2. Each time providing a translation for the page in the link

The first problem that I encounter is having the default routing for the @Route ("/") home page will not pass me localhost:8000/en/ because Symfony will look for the en controller, which is the choice of language, not the controller. The solution is to provide the path localhost:8000/index/en But at this moment I'm blocking the possibility of displaying the page by giving only the address of the page. The @Route option ("/{_ locale}", defaults = {"_locale" = "en"}) does not work and I do not understand why, because I always have to specify pl / en etc. to display the language.

When reading the documentation, I should do the following:

1. Configuration in the file config / packages / translation.yaml

default_locale: 'en' <- specifies the default language
translator: ~ 
fallbacks: ['en'] <- defines which language will be loaded if you provide an incorrect language via _locale

2. File: config / services.yaml parameters: locale: 'en'
3. The config / translation.yaml file

   framework:
   default_locale: 'en'
   translator: ~

Comment: What version of Symfony is your application based on?

Comment: Symfony 4.0.6  - PHP 7.2.2

Answer (score -2):

To make localization work for your users you have to follow three tutorials:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html and https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html The first one explains how to setup translations and how to use them. The second explains how to read the locale of the current session and that you should use _locale parameter to set your routes (as a prefix would be the best option in the beginning). The third tutorial explains how to make the locale sticky to user session (so that the user doesn't have to type the correct URL in the browser each time). All these work together, not as separate options.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, just for example, how should the language change look like? Can I do it from any controller? And I need to add _locale prefix to every controller? Can I have only one class or controller to change the language? Can any controller have the option of changing the language?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the _locale prefix to every route of the controllers you want to provide a translation for. Also you should set the requirements for the route. I recommend setting this as annotations, something like this:

@Route( "/{_locale}", name="index", defaults={"_locale" = "en"}, requirements={"_locale" = "en|de|fr|es"} )

Some may argue that this is not the best practice (to use annotations) but important thing it makes things more accessible. You don't have to set anything in the controller. Except creating a LocaleSubscriber.

Comment: As you will notice the LocaleSubscriber tries to detect the locale from the current route.

Comment: If this message was intended for me then I will have to disappoint you, I don't speak Polish. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry:) I understand that now. Thanks. Just what if the main page controller has Route ("/") routing so I can start the website via www.mypage.com if I set the routing to Route ("/ {_ locale}") I will not run the website via the address www.mypage .com because I will have to enter the _loacle parameter when entering the website address, and thus someone who wants to enter the site for the first time will have to provide the address www.mypage.com/{_locale} (en or other) which will cause the controller to start depending on parameter {_locale}. Is this the fault of configuration?

Comment: Set two routes, with different paths, for the same controller.

Comment: But what if the user visits the site for the first time and did not choose the language? LocaleSubscriber will automatically assign the default language to the session if Route ('/ {_ locale}' deafults = {"_ locale" = "en"}) will automatically assign the default language as en? The second thing is setting the language to configuration files, I should not use '% app.locales%'?

Comment: Another thing you can do for new users is to redirect the user to the page with the default locale and either store it in the a session or in a persistent cookie. Also, there is a tutorial on how to store the locale in the database (which can be used for registered users). Yes, by defining a default locale it should be set to the default. Have you read the documentation? You can experiment in code a little... That is the most rewarding experience.

Comment: That's how I read, but I understood that from the given pages I can choose one way to change translations on the site and not that all these methods work ONLY together. And every time I want to go to another controller and view, I have to give even getem even if I do not want to change the language? {{path ("/ my_new_route", {"_locale": app.request.getLocale ()})}} and if I want to change the language then I give a different locale but I have to set Route ("/ {_ locale} / my_new_route")?

Comment: You specify your locale in route with the _locale parameter. Something like Route ("/{_locale} /my_new_route");

Also you don't have to specify the locale in your templates. The locale service (sticky locale) takes care in detecting the locale.

Maybe I am not getting it right but it's a bit hard for me to understand your last question. Please try to rephrase. It would be easier if you would paste your code and explain which part exactly isn't working.

Comment: This question was about two things. Do I always have to enter the path with the locale parameter when I want to go to another controller? W twigu {{path ("/ my_new_route", {"locale": app.request.getLocale ()})}? If I do not give the current locale parameter, then this is going to be a mistake? If I want to change the language to another one, in this way? {{path (app.request.attributes.get ('_ route'), "app.request.attributes.get ('_ route_params')) | merge (" locale ":" new_lang "}}?

Comment: For the first question check the answer from fabpot on this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1700 Which says that "In master, the issue described by @beberlei has been fixed (but it's not possible to backport this fix to 2.0). So, the _locale argument is now always available and you don't need to pass it explicitly when generating a route for the current locale." For the second question, the correct parameter is _locale not locale.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help/
But when it comes to getting the locale from the database, I use the name of any field in the user table to save the value of the locale.I do not understand where the value of the locale for a given user is loaded from the database . I can do this in the controller code $request-> setLocale ($currentLoggedUser->getHisLocale()); but when changing the language has the same code in each controller. In the EventSubscriberInterface class, I load the regional settings for the user from the database and check if the language has changed?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html#setting-the-locale-based-on-the-user-s-preferences