# Translate locale symfony 4 twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, locale, symfony4

I have a question about the translation of a twig template.

This is an actual way to translate.

```
{% trans into 'en_EN' %}Hello{% endtrans %}!,
```

Can I load directly the '' value from a database like this? (this returns an error).

```
{% trans into {{ app.user.lang }} %}Hello{% endtrans %}!,
```

or shall I use a controller to do it?

I'm now using the following function to translate:

```
{% with %}
{% set lang = app.user.lang %}
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{% trans into lang %}Hello{% endtrans %}!, {{ app.user.username }}<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></button>
{% endwith %}
```

But I'm not sure if is a good practice or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `into`, if you want to have translations based on the user's preferences, you add it through a listener or include the locale in the URL's, then all you have to do in your twig templates is `{{ 'Hello' | trans }}`

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is nor really clear. Normally you can define a default language in your configuration file and then change them with a language selector or something else.

Then you don't need that `into`.

[Symfony 4 How to change language Step by Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637662/symfony-4-how-to-change-language-step-by-step)

Here is a good example how to build a language switch and some tutorials. You should read the documentation for translation where the most things are explained.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

When you really want to store your translations to your database you have to use a translation loader and extend them so you have to register a new service and load your translations from your database.

[Symfony2 Database Translation Loader isn't executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350866/symfony2-database-translation-loader-isnt-executed)

But i don't know if that was exactly your question.

Comment: Hi Stony, thanks for your reply, i just edited my first post seconds ago.